# Determining preference using a binomial test. Is this the right way to go?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Let's say you are running a blind essay on preference of a new product. You make people taste two different drinks and record their response. They prefer A and you record it as a failure in a Bernoulli test, they prefer B and you record it as a success.

Then the null hypothesis would be that the proportion of failure / success is 0.5 and the alternative hypothesis is that the proportion is not 0.5. Then we can perform a run of the mill hypothesis test and determine if we can reject the null hypothesis or not. After this I compute a p value, a confidence interval etc. I also computed the test's power and it looks decent.

Informally, if we fail to reject the null hypothesis we say that both products can't be deemed to have equal preference by subjects.

Does this make any sense? What other statistical test could I run to determine preference?

Comment: I would check out the difference between enumerative and analytic problems discussed here: "The exact environmental conditions for any experiment will never be seen again...What we need to know in a comparative study is...will B be better than A by the amount D IN FUTURE TRIALS?" [On Probability As a Basis For Action](https://www.deming.org/media/pdf/145.pdf). W. EDWARDS DEMING.The American Statistician, Vol. 29, No. 4, IPS, pp. 146152